# Is Play Framework good enough for next big app?

Tags: jakarta-ee, frameworks, playframework, scalability

I have been recently introduced to play and i must admit that it was almost like sliced bread for me. Without doubt Play is the best thing to happen in the Java world and kudos to Guillaume Bort and zenexity team for this awesome framework.

That being said, i haven't seen any mainstream facebook or twitter built on Play yet and i was wondering if it is good only for relatively simple apps? Here are some of the concerns/questions i have?

1) Security - With growth comes attention and is Play capable of handling hackers attentions? The cookie approach seems very basic, but there is no reason to doubt it is not sufficient?

2) Scalability - From what i have seen it seems scalable handling traffic and does a good job, anyone thinks it is not yet tested?

3) App complexity - How does play perform when you have models spanning 100's of beans, will it be able to handle complex apps? Most of the magic is possible because of Java reflection and might be a concern.

So from those who have used it and the creators, can you provide samples or examples of applications where Play has handled the above 3 concerns and is there anything one needs to keep in mind to handle the above concerns while working with Play? Basically to avoid the Twitter experience with RoR.

Comment: Off topic on Stack Overflow? While interesting, this question is likely to lead to subjective, long discussions...

Comment: Modified the question, but the main theme is still the same, i don't see a reason for above to turn into a flame war for frameworks, just generic questions which need answering from experts.

Answer (score 17):

I agree that there are not many reference sites that show how capable Play is for enterprise deployment. That said, there have been posts in the past from The Guardian (I think!), and also from LinkedIn, to show Play being used in some part of their deployments.

Further to the above, the creators of Play were using the concept of Play as an internal framework at Zenexity prior to open sourcing the framework in 2008/9. They used it for many commercial applications, and have demonstrated that they have large deployments (have quoted that they have deployed to banks and government applications).

More and more job applications are being advertised for Play developers, so there is definite movement in the industry to adopt Play for larger deployments.

For me, I would not choose anything else any more. Especially if I were doing projects for clients, and it allows me to have a competitive advantage over competing companies, as I have a far better productivity with Play than they can with other Java technologies.

Comment: +! "I would not choose anything else any more." < If I can avoid it, no more Spring/JEE companies for me :)

Comment: I wish I could afford the luxury of being able to pick and choose the frameworks I work with. In case anyone's wondering, it would probably be Play as well :-)